# Saving children and father doesn't see them

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, jpa, ejb, jpa-2.0

I have a Category with many discussions like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="category", fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
List<Discussion> discussions =  new ArrayList<Discussion>();
```

and by saving a new discussion with

```
Discussion discussion = new Discussion();
discussion.setCategory(category);
discussion.setTitle(text);
discussionFacade.create(discussion);
```

By calling category.getDiscussions(); I don't see the new one (until I redeploy).
What's the best method? I don't want to create a method that adds the discussion on the Category (ex. category.addDiscussion(discussion).

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with bi-directional associations, you're supposed to write some convenience methods to actually set the associations on both ends.

After persisting the entity considered as the owning side, the underlying JPA provider will figure out whether it must persist the associated entities (depending on the CASCADING configuration) but by default the entity (in your case, the Discussion instance) is managed by the persistence context but not refreshed from the DB. So, this is a normal behavior.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that I cann't persist directly the child object, I thought  it automatically updates the upper object (Category in this case)

Answer (score 1):

The list will not be updated until you `refresh()` the entity from the database. But you don't need a separate method, use the `add` method of your `ArrayList`:

```
discussions.add(discussion);
```